# Math with Enums (e.g. DayOfWeek) in C#

Tags: c#, enums, dayofweek

Why is it that the following code won't work:

```
endDate.AddDays(7-endDate.DayOfWeek);
```

While this will:

```
endDate.AddDays(0-endDate.DayOfWeek + 7);
```

?

(By "won't work" I mean results in the following compilation error: "cannot convert from 'System.DayOfWeek' to 'double'")

Comment: For some interesting analysis of compiler bugs involving this feature, see:

http://blogs.gotdotnet.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/03/28/the-root-of-all-evil-part-one.aspx

and

http://blogs.gotdotnet.com/ericlippert/archive/2006/03/29/the-root-of-all-evil-part-two.aspx

Comment: For anyone looking for the Eric's blog posts, they've moved to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/03/28/the-root-of-all-evil-part-one.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/03/29/the-root-of-all-evil-part-two.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To expand upon what Lasse said (or rather, make it a little more explicit).

Because 0 is convertable to an Enum type,

```
0 - endDate.DayOfWeek becomes 
(DayOfWeek)0 - endDate.DayOfWeek
```

And since you can subtract one enum from another and get an integer difference:

```
(DayOfWeek)0 - endDate.DayOfWeek == (int)endDate.DayOfWeek
```

Thus, since the result of the subtraction is an int, you can then add 7 to it.

```
endDate.AddDays(0-endDate.DayOfWeek + 7);
```

So, if Monday's Enum value is 1

```
0 - endDate.DayOfWeek == -1 + 7 == 6
```

However, you can't do the reverse.

```
endDate.DayOfWeek - 0 + 7,
```

because the result type of the calculation is dependant upon the leftmost side.   Thus, while 0 - endDate.DayOfWeek results in an integer, endDate.DayOfWeek - 0 results in an enum DayOfWeek.

Most interestingly, you could use this side-effect to get the value of an enum without casting, though I would consider this hackish and confusing... thus to be avoided.

```
int enumValue = -(0 - endDate.DayOfWeek);
```

Answer (score 4):

This is very interesting.  The right way to do this is:

```
endDate.AddDays(7 - (int)endDate.DayOfWeek);
```

But, your question isn't about a solution, but a reason for the behavior.  It has something to do with the way the compiler treats a zero.  Either line fails if no zero is present, while both lines work if a zero is present.

Comment: Additionally endDate.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Sunday - e.DayOfWeek) does work.  It's converting zero into the Sunday field of DayOfWeek.  Now what's really odd is the "zero trick" fails for addition.  Meaning endDate.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Sunday + e.DayOfWeek) will not compile.

Answer (score 4):

You can subtract two enum values to get their integer value difference:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication10
{
    public enum X { A, B, C, D }
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var x = X.D + X.A;
            Console.Out.WriteLine(x);
            Console.In.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Will print out 3.

But you can't add, probably makes no sense.

In the case of "0", 0 is auto-convertible to all enum types, so basically "0 - enumvalue" means the same as "(enumtype)0 - enumvalue", which again works.